# Make Input For User In Python-Telegram-Bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

i want to make a input for user in python-telegram-bot, but i dont know whats make input command in python-telegram-bot.
for exam:
user press on "enter name" button and bot wait for user input, after that user entered name bot say hello to that name

Answer (score 0):

If you want predefined options (buttons) then you can use `InlineKeyboardButton`

```
def add_suggested_actions(update, context):
  options = []

  options.append(InlineKeyboardButton('Enter Name', callback_data='name'))
  options.append(InlineKeyboardButton('Enter Age', callback_data='age'))

  reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup([options])

  context.bot.send_message(chat_id='chat_id', text='Choose an option', reply_markup=reply_markup)
```

Once the use chooses an option the `callback_data` is sent to your bot which can follow up the request (ie ask What is your name?)

Comment: can i make input with out inlinekeyboardbutton?

Comment: The `inlinekeyboardbutton` is to offer a predefined choice (button), if you want the user to type (free text) then you just deal with the incoming text message